# Best way to write a Gitlab module

Tags: gitlab

I would like to extend Gitlab, mainly writing a custom dashboard.  I cannot find any documentation on the 'proper/best/better' way to do this.  Can someone point me in the right direction.  I already tried searching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way of doing that except by forking GitLab.

The only way of doing those things without forking (and thus merging afterwards...) is the API (since it is guaranteed to be stable) but it is probably overkill for your application.

Answer (score 1):

Ciro Santilli is correct. With GitLab, there is no way of writing custom modules for GitLab. Such as a custom dashboard.

According to GitLab license, only GitLab the company is allowed to write modules for GitLab. This is because all their modules are Closed Source (Proprietary) license. Owned and controlled by GitLab.

---

Below is the same as above. But with details if you're interested in those.

GitLab's business model is "Open-core". Which means the core of the software is Libre Source (Open Source). But all its modules are Closed Source. Read more at:

• https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-core_model

• https://archive.li/i7gq8

If you're asking because you need a software with a license which allows you to write custom modules. Then you need another software with a Libre Source license for both its core and its modules. So that you would be allowed to write your own custom dashboard module. In turn, it is likely that you would have access to plenty of documentation about the 'proper/best/better' way to write your own module. Which was the other part of your question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34670223)